# How to add a task in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `HTML/JS` code as shown below in which on click of Execute button, I want to display:

```
[{"detail":"Hello World"},{"detail":"Great News"}]
```

Currently, on clicking Execute button I am getting the following:

```
[{"detail":""},{"detail":""}]
```

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the JS code below so that on click of a Execute button, I am able to display:

```
[{"detail":"Hello World"},{"detail":"Great News"}]
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="submit" onClick="runCode()" value="Execute" >
 <div id="console-log">
 </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
})

function runCode(){
var td=new Todo()
td.addTask("Hello World")
td.addTask("Great News")
td.printList()
}


class Todo{
    constructor(name) {
        this.todolist = [];
        
        
        this.task={
            'detail':''
        }
      }
    
    addToList(newobj)
    {
        this.todolist.push(newobj)
     
    }
    addTask(taskDetail){
    
                    this.task.detail=taskDetail
            this.todolist.push(this.task)
            this.task.detail='' //clear data for next step
    
    }
    printList()
    {
            var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

            var text= JSON.stringify(this.todolist)
         $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
        //alert(this.todolist)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push an object created just from the argument into the `todolist` property:

```
addTask(detail) {
  this.todolist.push({ detail });
}
```

The `this.task` property only makes things more confusing, I'd recommend avoiding it.

```js
function runCode() {
  var td = new Todo()
  td.addTask("Hello World")
  td.addTask("Great News")
  td.printList()
}


class Todo {
  constructor(name) {
    this.todolist = [];
  }
  addTask(detail) {
    this.todolist.push({ detail });
  }
  printList() {
    var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

    var text = JSON.stringify(this.todolist)
    $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text))
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" onClick="runCode()" value="Execute">
<div id="console-log">
</div>
```

It would also be trivial to remove the dependency on the big jQuery library if you wanted, it's not accomplishing anything useful. Also, it'd be good practice to [use `addEventListener` instead of an inline handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var td = new Todo()
  td.addTask("Hello World")
  td.addTask("Great News")
  td.printList()
});


class Todo {
  constructor(name) {
    this.todolist = [];
  }
  addTask(detail) {
    this.todolist.push({ detail });
  }
  printList() {
    document.querySelector('code').appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
      .textContent = JSON.stringify(this.todolist);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Execute">
<code>
</code>
```